# How to call a Groovy Closure with an Object Array

Tags: groovy

I may be misunderstanding how to use varargs, but according to the [Groovy Docs for Closures](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#call(java.lang.Object...)), for the function `public V call(Object... args)` , the arguments parameter "could be a single value or a List of values".

But when I try to do something like this:

```
Closure myClosure = { arg1, arg2, arg3 ->
    println arg1 == null
    println arg2 == null
    println arg3 == null
}
 Object[] argsArray = new Object[]{"John", "Jack", "Mack"}
 myClosure.call(argsArray)
```

The compiler throws an groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: .call() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.Object;)

I couldn't even get the varargs function to work when passing in an actual varargs either.

```
def myVarargsFunction(Object... args){
    println "myVarargsFunction"
    myClosure.call(args)
}
```

This code results in the same error (After I change the scope of `Closure myClosure` of course).
I don't under stand why either or these situations do not work. I know there are other ways to get this to work, I just want to understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the spread operator:

```
    myClosure.call(*args)
```